# XSLT3.0 | JSON-XML Conversion

Tags: java, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to convert json to xml using xslt 3.0 (Saxon-HE v11.4 library) in Java.

While i'm able to convert the complete json to xml, i need guidance in writing a custom logic to pick and choose keys that needs to be in final xml.

XSLT being used currently -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:param name="inputJson" />

    <xsl:template name="init">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="json-to-xml($inputJson)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to keep json keys as xml keys -->
    <xsl:template match="*[@key]">
        <xsl:element name="{@key}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to remove namespace -->
    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample json -

```
{
    "name": "user",
    "age": 20,
    "designation": "engineer",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "address": "sample address 1"
        },
        {
            "type": "work",
            "address": "sample address 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Current XML Output (which needs fix, as individual type/address element is not surrounded by addresses tag) -

```
<name>user</name>
<age>20</age>
<designation>engineer</designation>
<addresses>
   <type>home</type>
   <address>sample address 1</address>
   <type>work</type>
   <address>sample address 2</address>
</addresses>
```

I would need the final XML to have name , age and home address.
Sample expected XML -

```
<name>user</name>
<age>20</age>
<home-address>
    <addressLine>sample address 1</addressLine>
</home-address>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use various transformation steps with e.g. different modes or write conditions in your match patterns like e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'addresses']">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fn:map[fn:string[@key = 'address'] and fn:string[@key = 'type']]">
  <xsl:element name="{fn:string[@key = 'type']}-address">
    <addressLine>{fn:string[@key = 'address']}</addressLine>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

That needs `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` and `expand-text="yes"` on e.g. the `xsl:stylesheet` root element.

[Fiddle example](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20xmlns%3Afn%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Astrip-space%20elements%3D%22*%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20omit-xml-declaration%3D%22yes%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22inputJson%22%20as%3D%22xs%3Astring%22%20expand-text%3D%22no%22%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22user%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2020%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22designation%22%3A%20%22engineer%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22addresses%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22home%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22sample%20address%201%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22work%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22sample%20address%202%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%22json-to-xml%28%24inputJson%29%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20template%20to%20keep%20json%20keys%20as%20xml%20keys%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22*%5B%40key%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aelement%20name%3D%22%7B%40key%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aelement%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20template%20to%20remove%20namespace%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22data%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aelement%20name%3D%22%7Blocal-name%28%29%7D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%20%7C%20node%28%29%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aelement%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22fn%3Aarray%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27addresses%27%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22fn%3Amap%5Bfn%3Astring%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27address%27%5D%20and%20fn%3Astring%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27type%27%5D%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aelement%20name%3D%22%7Bfn%3Astring%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27type%27%5D%7D-address%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CaddressLine%3E%7Bfn%3Astring%5B%40key%20%3D%20%27address%27%5D%7D%3C%2FaddressLine%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aelement%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=&input-type=None).